# url_for in Flask always return error 304,even after clearing caches in chrome

Tags: python, flask

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="font-size: 16px;">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Login">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="page_type" content="np-template-header-footer-from-plugin">
    <title>Arcade</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="{{ url_for('static',filename='css/nicepage.css') }}" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href=" {{ url_for('static',filename='CSS/Arcade.css') }}" media="screen">
    <script class="u-script" type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static',filename='JS/jquery.js') }}" defer=""></script>
    <script class="u-script" type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static',filename='JS/nicepage.js') }}" defer=""></script>
    <meta name="generator" content="Nicepage 4.10.5, nicepage.com">
    <link id="u-theme-google-font" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i|Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i">
    
    
    <script type="application/ld+json">{
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": ""
}</script>
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#478ac9">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Arcade">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
  </head>
  <body class="u-body u-xl-mode"><header class="u-clearfix u-header u-palette-1-light-1 u-header" id="sec-bc93"><div class="u-clearfix u-sheet u-sheet-1">
        <nav class="u-menu u-menu-dropdown u-offcanvas u-menu-1">
          <div class="menu-collapse" style="font-size: 1rem; letter-spacing: 0px;">
            <a class="u-button-style u-custom-left-right-menu-spacing u-custom-padding-bottom u-custom-top-bottom-menu-spacing u-nav-link u-text-active-palette-1-base u-text-hover-palette-2-base" href="#">
              <svg class="u-svg-link" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#menu-hamburger"></use></svg>
              <svg class="u-svg-content" version="1.1" id="menu-hamburger" viewBox="0 0 16 16" x="0px" y="0px" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g><rect y="1" width="16" height="2"></rect><rect y="7" width="16" height="2"></rect><rect y="13" width="16" height="2"></rect>
</g></svg>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="u-custom-menu u-nav-container">
            <ul class="u-nav u-unstyled u-nav-1"><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link u-text-active-palette-1-base u-text-hover-palette-2-base" style="padding: 10px 20px;">Home</a>
</li><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link u-text-active-palette-1-base u-text-hover-palette-2-base" href="About.html" style="padding: 10px 20px;">About</a>
</li><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link u-text-active-palette-1-base u-text-hover-palette-2-base" href="Contact.html" style="padding: 10px 20px;">Contact</a>
</li><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link u-text-active-palette-1-base u-text-hover-palette-2-base" style="padding: 10px 20px;">Profile</a>
</li></ul>
          </div>
          <div class="u-custom-menu u-nav-container-collapse">
            <div class="u-black u-container-style u-inner-container-layout u-opacity u-opacity-95 u-sidenav">
              <div class="u-inner-container-layout u-sidenav-overflow">
                <div class="u-menu-close"></div>
                <ul class="u-align-center u-nav u-popupmenu-items u-unstyled u-nav-2"><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link">Home</a>
</li><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link" href="About.html">About</a>
</li><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link" href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
</li><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link">Profile</a>
</li></ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="u-black u-menu-overlay u-opacity u-opacity-70"></div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div></header>
    <section class="u-clearfix u-section-1" id="sec-24f5">
      <div class="u-clearfix u-expanded-width u-gutter-0 u-layout-wrap u-layout-wrap-1">
        <div class="u-gutter-0 u-layout">
          <div class="u-layout-row">
            <div class="u-align-center u-container-style u-image u-layout-cell u-size-30 u-image-1" data-image-width="1200" data-image-height="900">
              <div class="u-container-layout u-container-layout-1" src=""></div>
            </div>
            <div class="u-align-left u-container-style u-layout-cell u-size-30 u-white u-layout-cell-2">
              <div class="u-container-layout u-container-layout-2">
                <h2 class="u-text u-text-default u-text-1">Login</h2>
                <div class="u-form u-form-1">
                  <form action="#" method="POST" class="u-clearfix u-form-spacing-10 u-form-vertical u-inner-form" source="custom" name="form" style="padding: 10px;">
                    <div class="u-form-group u-form-name">
                      <label for="name-e834" class="u-label">Username</label>
                      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Username" id="name-e834" name="name" class="u-border-1 u-border-grey-30 u-input u-input-rectangle u-white" required="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="u-form-email u-form-group">
                      <label for="email-e834" class="u-label">Password</label>
                      <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your Password" id="email-e834" name="email" class="u-border-1 u-border-grey-30 u-input u-input-rectangle u-white" required="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="u-align-center u-form-group u-form-submit">
                      <a href="#" class="u-active-palette-1-base u-border-none u-btn u-btn-submit u-button-style u-hover-custom-color-1 u-palette-1-base u-btn-1">Submit</a>
                      <input type="submit" value="submit" class="u-form-control-hidden">
                    </div>
                    <div class="u-form-send-message u-form-send-success"> Thank you! Your message has been sent. </div>
                    <div class="u-form-send-error u-form-send-message"> Unable to send your message. Please fix errors then try again. </div>
                    <input type="hidden" value="" name="recaptchaResponse">
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    
    
    <footer class="u-align-center u-clearfix u-footer u-grey-80 u-footer" id="sec-48a0"><div class="u-align-left u-clearfix u-sheet u-sheet-1"></div></footer>
    <section class="u-backlink u-clearfix u-grey-80">
      <a class="u-link" href="https://nicepage.com/website-templates" target="_blank">
        <span>Website Templates</span>
      </a>
      <p class="u-text">
        <span>created with</span>
      </p>
      <a class="u-link" href="" target="_blank">
        <span>Website Builder Software</span>
      </a>. 
    </section><span style="height: 64px; width: 64px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 0px; background-image: none; right: 20px; bottom: 20px; padding: 15px;" class="u-back-to-top u-black u-icon u-icon-circle u-opacity u-opacity-85" data-href="#">
        <svg class="u-svg-link" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice" viewBox="0 0 551.13 551.13"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-1d98"></use></svg>
        <svg class="u-svg-content" enable-background="new 0 0 551.13 551.13" viewBox="0 0 551.13 551.13" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg-1d98"><path d="m275.565 189.451 223.897 223.897h51.668l-275.565-275.565-275.565 275.565h51.668z"></path></svg>
    </span>
  </body>
</html>
```

The above is my HTML code.I have used url_for for rendering the template with css.

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
   

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
   return render_template('Arcade.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.debug = True
   app.run()
   app.run(debug = True)
```

The above is my python flask code. When i tried to run the code i got 304 erroe.So i cleared my browser cache and tried to rehost the application. But still the url_for couldn't grab the css and js files properly. No matter how many times i clear the cache and try I couldn't get the expected result.Please look into it and help me.
Note: I have properly created a static folder and saved the css and js files in a separate folders namely JS and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving this error because the cached version of the requested file is the same as the file to be sent.

Fix it by:

1. `Clear the Chrome's Cache Data.`
2. It is possible that a `Computer Malware` might be causing that problem, so `run a Malware Scan.`

   - As a precautionary step, I'd suggest you also `disable any extensions` you have installed on your browser.

**Other Potential Problems**

If it hasn't been solved by any of the methods above, it might be a DNS issue.

1. Go to DNS settings
2. Click  `clear host cache`